# React render prop method is not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, render

I want the function FetchAll.getAll() to be called from the AddTracker.addOne() method

Here's the UI component I'm exporting called FetchAll with the method called getAll

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class FetchAll extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    trackers: null,
  };

  getAll = async () => {
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:8181/trackers");
    const json = await res.json();
    this.setState({ trackers: json.data, loading: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.render(
          this.state.loading,
          this.state.trackers,
          this.getAll
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The Navbar Component that's importing FetchAll then passing in the getAll prop to the AssTracker component

```
import React from "react";

import { AddTracker, FetchAll } from "./index";
import { Navbar} from "react-bootstrap";

export default function NavComponent(props) {

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar >
        <FetchAll
          render={(loading, trackers, getAll) => {
            return <AddTracker getAll={getAll} />;
          }}
        />
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}
```

The AddTracker component where I want the props.getAll function to be called

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const DB = "http://localhost:8181/trackers";

export default function AddTracker(props) {
  function formClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let dataObj = { url: formData };

    const addOne = async () => {
        let res = await fetch(DB, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
        const text = await res.text();
        console.log(text);
        return text;
      };
      const runFirst = async () => {
        await addOne();
        props.getAll(); // nothing happens
        console.log(props.getAll()); // Promise {<pending>}
        console.log(props); // {getAll: f}

      };
      runFirst();
    }
  

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <Form inline>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFormData(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={(e) => formClick(e)}>
          Add Tracker
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I can not get props.getAll() to be called inside of AddTracker. I've tried calling it directly inside of addOne, I've tried extracting it to a constant in the outer scope per vscode. I'm not sure what else to try.I've got it working in another component which makes it all the more perplexing.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Stack overflow is not exactly a discussion forum or a place people would help solve complex code issues. It is more of a place to figure out concept or more abstract level problems.
You need to simplify your code as much as possible, remove anything that is not relevant and put the least possible amount of code were the problem still exists. You will probably figure out the issue yourself if u do it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it down to the only the relevant code.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I did want to note that there is plenty more to be done in terms of simplifying the code here to make it easier for people to answer. E.g. do you really need to keep the `placeholder` property on the `<FormControl>`? And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've removed more code.

Comment: @outoftime The question is why isn't `props.getAll()` being called in the `addOne()` function.  Per your advice I've removed props from from being added to `addOne()` but still no luck.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not being called?

Answer (score 0):

Itʼs not clear from your question what problem you are encountering, but I notice that your `addOne()` function has a `props` parameter that shadows the `props` of the `AddTracker` component. So Iʼm guessing `props.getAll` is undefined where you try to call it because `getAll()` is a property of the outer (shadowed) `props`.

The eslint [`no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) rule is helpful for making this kind of problem more immediately obvious.

Comment: The question is why isn't `props.getAll()` being called in the `addOne()` function.

Comment: OK, if you still have the same problem in the updated code, then this answer does not apply.